# sqoop hive import "has not been cleaned" exception

Tags: hive, sqoop

When I try to run the following sqoop command

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://hostname.com:3306/retail_db \
--username **** \
--password **** \
--table customers \
--hive-import \
--hive-database hariharan_hive \
--hive-table hivecustomers \
--hive-overwrite
```

I’m getting an exception as

> " Failed with exception Destination directory
>   hdfs://nn01.itversity.com:8020/apps/hive/warehouse/hariharan_hive.db/hivecustomers
>   has not be cleaned up. "

[image]

but the path given in the exception does not exist..
can anybody help me on this?..

Comment: if passworrd and hostname are real please change it to take one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about clearing the Hive metastore by the following command:

```
(hive shell)> msck repair table hariharan_hive.hivecustomers;
```